# How to skip exception in nested block

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, plsqldeveloper

I have 2 nested blocks in my program. If any error occurs in the 1st nested block then program will not execute further, and it will go to exception section and exit from the overall program.
But I do not want to be exit from my program. My program need to be executed for the 2nd nested block and further also, even an exception is raised in 1st nested block.

If I have program like this:

```
DECLARE
    var_out VARCHAR2(10):= 'OUTER';
BEGIN
    <<INNER1>>
    DECLARE
        var_in1  NUMBER:='INNER 1';
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_in1);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
    END;

    <<INNER2>>
    DECLARE
        var_in2 VARCHAR2(10):='INNER 2';
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_in2);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
    END;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_out);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
```

in my program inner1 block will throw `value error exception` so the overall program will not be executed.

How do I execute inner2 and outer block, even exception raised in inner1 block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your exception in `INNER1` occurs within the declaration section, it is beyond the scope of the block's exception handler. You need to wrap the whole `INNER1` block in another block with its own exception handler.

```
declare
    var_out varchar2(10):= 'OUTER';
begin
    <<INNER1>>
    begin
        declare
            var_in1  number:='INNER 1';
        begin
            dbms_output.put_line(var_in1);
        exception
            when others then
                dbms_output.put_line('Error in innermost INNER1');
        end;
    exception
        when others then
            dbms_output.put_line('Error in INNER1 wrapper');
    end;

    <<INNER2>>
    declare
        var_in2 varchar2(10):='INNER 2';
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line(var_in2);
    exception
        when others then 
            dbms_output.put_line('Error in INNER2');
    end;
    dbms_output.put_line(var_out);
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Error at top level');
end;
```

Output:

```
Error in INNER1 wrapper
INNER 2
OUTER
```

Probably both `OTHERS` handlers are not needed - the above is just to illustrate the structure.

Comment: thank you @william . some illiterate people were down voted my question and said, that is not possible in PL/SQL.